# SSMS: Dragging vertical tab group divider and nothing happens

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

I've searched Google for "ssms vertical drag divider nothing happens" but can't find anything. Am I the only one experiencing this?

I'm using both SSMS 17 and 18, as some servers I work with is too new for SSMS 17, but I also need the debug function which is missing from 18. 17 is my default and I can't remember seeing it in 18.

The issue (in at least SSMS 17) is this:

I often have two tab groups and a vertical divider between them. I often adjust this divider left or right to make room for different tab contents. But something is off with my install of SSMS 17, as very often, nothing happens when I drag the divider. I expect the divider to move to where I release it, but it stays the same.

See screen recording: https://www.loom.com/share/a8fd8759c7b647d18976bc0cf96ffef7

- SSMS 17.9.1
- SSMS 18.9.2

Is there any extra logging I can enable to help with this?

Best regards
SvendK

**Update**
I changed to use SSMS 18.9.2 as default .sql-file opener, and then I have to open SSMS 17.9.1 if I have to debug. That makes the problem less occurring. I haven't heard from Logitech and I don't have time to further pursue this. I'll leave the question here, so other people can find it when googling, but realise it will never get an answer. I guess it's just some sort of bug in SSMS 17.9.1 related to the different ways my laptops mousepad and my mice works.

Comment: Could you try it with another mouse?

Comment: Oh jesus... I first thought: "Yeah, thanks for the great advice (ironically)", but then I tried with the mouse pad on the laptop. Works every time. What the ** Logitech? I have loved my MX Anywhere 3 up until five seconds ago! Thanks, why didn't I think of this?

Comment: I wonder what it does wrong. It clearly shows a click and drag, but when released SSMS ignores it.

Comment: I have asked Logitech to hear what the difference is. I can drag the main window of SSMS without problems, it's only the tab group divider, so I guess the problem lies withing SSMS, but I'd like some info from Logitech to whatever the difference between clicking with the mouse and the mouse pad. Stay tuned... :-)

Comment: Okay, more info: If I CLICK with the mousepad but DRAG with the mouse, same problem, but if I both CLICK and DRAG with the mousepad, it works fine. And if I CLICK with the mouse and DRAG with the mouse pad, it also works fine. I guess the moving of the mouse is just not registered inside of SSMS. 

So the question is: What is the difference between dragging the mouse and dragging the mouse pad. Why is there a difference?

Comment: Same problem with another mouse and receiver (Logitech M705). Now Logitech Live Chat has registered a ticket with it. Now we play the waiting game.

Comment: Let me suggest to close the question because in fact, it is not a DBA question. I use a M705 and I have similar issues when the mouse is getting old. (Apparently old, I think they call it "planned obsolescence")

Comment: It is 100% a software issue. If I click and hold with the mouse, but drag the divider to the side with the mouse pad, then it works, but dragging with the mouse doesn't work. You can still see both the mouse cursor and the divider "shadow" moving so the drag is registered, but somehow "forgotten" once mouse button is released. Also tried with two mice and receivers. I just can't see what the difference is. Is the mouse pad registering the drag as another event than using the normal mice?

I agree this is not about DBs but about how SSMS is build/programmed. Is there a better forum for that?

Comment: @Svendk Software issue != DBA (Database Administration) issue. At this point your question does not sound relevant to this forum, and it's unlikely anyone here can provide you with the answer you seek. Please continue to work with Logitech if you need. Additionally, generally comments are not where updates should be posted, rather you should put updates in your original post accordingly (just some advice for future questions). Finally, I'd recommend using the latest version of SSMS (especially if that eliminates your issue).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @J.D. and sorry for the delay. I have updated the question with my outcome. Yes, I could have updated the question along the way. And yes, it could have been posted elsewhere, but this is very specific to this tool/app which a lot of DBA's use, so I needed some specific expertise here.